# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, web

This is a demo of data that is read from the firebase database,

> **without the .includes('')**, *it works very fine, but i want it to only show data that is typed in a textField*

- I only posted the important part, StackOverflow will not approve my question if it has too many codes*

```
const arr = [
  { age: 1, name: 'Raphael' },
  { age: 3, name: 'Inyang' },
  { age: 6, name: 'Ifiok' },
  { age: 8, name: 'Ekpedeme' },
];

<ul style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}>
  {arr.map(function (item) {
    return (
      <li>
        <div
          style={{
           
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            width: 'auto',
            fontSize: 'calc(4px + 2vmin)',
            display: item.name.includes('Raphael') ? 'flex : 'none',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
          }}>
          <p>
            {item.name}: {item.age}
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

it keeps showing me the error above, what could be wrong,
**Please, is there another workaround?**

Comment: `item.age` is an integer, so what would `.includes` do?

Comment: i'll update that, its a typo

Comment: wow, i never thought of that

Comment: but, I don't just want something straight, i'll prefer a continuous search while I continue typing

Comment: I'm unsure why your seeing that error as in this example, `item.name` will never be undefined and that is your problem. In general though, this is the wrong approach with React. You don't want to hide items with display, but never have them in the dom at all. So filter, then render elements that you want displayed.

Comment: You should output `item.name` to the console for each item, if it's ever undefined... Then that's where to start looking for your problem.

Comment: is there a way to use filter in this example? I'll accept it as an answer

Comment: yes, in the data from the database, not all slots have the namespace filled

Comment: Answer updated to filter out items without a name property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your subsequent question about using filter, instead of map with display set to none.

```
const arr = [
  { age: 1, name: 'Raphael' },
  { age: 3, name: 'Inyang' },
  { age: 6, name: 'Ifiok' },
  { age: 8 },
];

const filtered = arr.filter(
  item => item.hasOwnProperty('name') && item.name.includes('Raphael')
);

<ul style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}>
  {filtered.map(function (item) {
    return (
      <li>
        <div
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            width: 'auto',
            fontSize: 'calc(4px + 2vmin)',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
          }}>
          <p>
            {item.name}: {item.age}
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

On my phone so not tested.

Edit: Now also filters out array entries which do not have a name property

Comment: it didnt work,you changed it, i'll try again

Comment: I recommend you create a Minimum Reproduceable Example on a code sandbox website to demonstrate your problem

Comment: like you said,the problem is likely that there are some parts of the array that is empty

Comment: based on w3 schools, it said that it returns undefined to an unknown value.
So, what other alternatives from .includes, .filter, that doesn't require prefilled values

Comment: Yes, but by filtering out items that have no `name` property, that should have been mitigated.

Comment: Error i keep getting
```×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
(anonymous function)


> 2709 | const addingStudents = online.filter( item => item.hasOwnProperty('name') && item.name.includes('Raphael'))
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `console.log(item)` for each item then you can see the item for the failure case and figure out why it happened